# How do I calculate time from pulse width?

Tags: voltage, power, current, diodes, power-electronics

I am looking into the LL4148 datasheet and notices the IFSM is rated for 1A @ pulse width = 1s and 2A @ pulse width = 1us. The goal is to calculate the energy pulse using E = IVt.

The current and voltage are known but I am unsure on how to convert the pulse width into time.

For example, if the datasheet gives the cycle as 4A @ 1 cycle (60Hz) then t = 8.3ms, but that's not the case here.

Datasheet: Mfr. No: LL4148

[image]

Comment: It's to do with heating: how long the power will be dissipated for, leading to how much a temperature rise and whether that heat will damage the part or shorten its life.

Comment: 2) Onsemi should be consulted on applications involving pulsed or low-duty-cycle operations. => means there is just not enough info in the data sheet for thorough specification of pulsed operation, though you can make some estaimtes.

Comment: Are you just looking to convert the 1 uS to seconds? (1 uS = 0.000001 S).  The IFSM specification is just the maximum current that the device can pass without damage in that period of time.

Comment: @Nedd S = Siemens. s = second.

Comment: @winny - of course.